# Adding action to ag-grid rows on hover with processRowPostCreate

Tags: ag-grid

Below is the effect that I would like on the grid. It seems like processRowPostCreate is the callback which I need, but I am confused as to how exactly it is supposed to be used. Should I modify the params.eRow.outerHTML to match my needs? Is there a better way? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think you *might* be better off with a [cellRenderer component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) especially if you want the icons to perform actions...